# How to use multiple targets in AlchemyAPI targeted sentiment analysis?

Tags: alchemyapi

When using AlchemyAPI Language for targeted sentiment analysis, the [docs](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/sentiment/textc.html#targetedsentiment) indicate that you can specify either `target` or `targets`. Specifying `targets` causes the response to contain an array, however I cannot figure out how to specify multiple targets in a single call.

Specifying a single target (but using the `targets` parameter):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "text=I love cats. Dogs are the worst." -d "targets=cats" -d "outputMode=json" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/text/TextGetTargetedSentiment?apikey=MY_API_KEY"
```

Does the service support multiple targets? And if so, how do I pass them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has been updated with the answer to this: http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/sentiment/textc.html#targetedsentiment

The solution is to use pipe characters: dogs|cats.

Full example:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "text=I love cats. Dogs are the worst." -d "targets=cats|dogs"  -d "outputMode=json"    "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/text/TextGetTargetedSentiment?apikey=MY_API_KEY"
```